# Is there a continuation-like type for wrapping an execution block, like (Ctx => R) => R or (=> R) => R?

Tags: scala, continuations

I'm looking for such a type that would allow me to represent a context, in which a piece of code is run. For example:

```
def withinContext[R]: ((=> R) => R) =
  (inner) => {
    initializeSomeResource()
    try {
      inner
    } finally {
      releaseTheResource()
    }
  }
```

which then I can use simply as

```
withinContext {
  ...
}
```

Or, if the inner block of code needs some information from the context,  generalize it as

```
def withinContext[R]: ((Ctx => R) => R) = ...
```

Their use cases roughly correspond to Haskell's [`bracket_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:bracket_) and [`bracket`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:bracket).

I could use the types `(=> R) => R` and `(A => R) => R` directly, but then I have no utility functions for combining such context wrappers, so I wonder, **is there anything like that already existing in the Scala ecosystem?**

The closes thing I know is [`scala.util.control.Exception.Catch`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.Exception$$Catch), which provides nice functions for constructing and combining `Catch` instances, but there seems to be no way for running any initialization before the inner block is executed. Also (this isn't so important to my use-case) it doesn't allow giving a parameter to the inner computation, like in the case `(A => R) => R`.

The type `(A => R) => R` is the continuation monad, corresponding to Haskell's [`ContT r IO a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#t:ContT), but I couldn't find an implementation of the continuation monad in any standard Scala library (maybe it's hidden somewhere deep in Scalaz where I missed it).

Comment: Not that this helps at all, but for my own understanding, would it make sense to define withinContext as `def withinContext[R](r: => R): R`?

Comment: @acjay That's true, I just wanted to point out the complete type I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I do this sort of thing fairly often for use with Specs2 test code. Essentially we want some context set up to surround a block of code. The idiom I use is like this:

```
def contextName[TYPE,RSRC](doit: (RSRC) => TYPE) : TYPE = {
  val thing : RSRC = acquireResource(args)
  try doit(thing)
  finally releaseResource(thing)
}
```

I realize you are trying to make a continuation of a continuation, but I have to ask: why? The idiom I've just given is a continuation monad of type (RSRC => TYPE) => TYPE and it can be used just as you've suggested with your `withContext`.  For example, a real use case from a ReactiveMongo context object I've written:

```
def withDatabase[T](dbName: String)(doit: (DefaultDB) => T) : T = {
  val db = connection.db(dbName)
  try doit(db)
  finally db.drop()
}
```

This acquires a database, passes it to the continuation and then drops the database when it is done even if the continuation throws an exception.  It gets used like this:

```
val numCollections = withDatabase("foo") { db => 
  db.collectionNames.map { list => list.size } 
}
```

Which simply uses the database to obtain a (future) number of collections in the database.

Hope this helps.